# Apostrophe in Textarea PHP

Tags: php, request, textarea, apostrophe

I have a textarea that is part of a form that submits to a PHP file.

The problem is that when an apostrophe (’) is entered into the textarea, the corresponding REQUEST variable in PHP turns up empty ($_REQUEST['description']). If there is no apostrophe, the $_REQUEST['description'] contains the textarea text as intended. Entering punctuation like single quotes and double quotes also works but an apostrophe does not. The same problem occurs for `<input type="text"></input>` as well. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: php won't trash that, but maybe your server has a security module (suhosin?) that's doing it for you.

Comment: Apostrophe and single quote are the same character. How is the form being submitted back? Javascript?

Comment: Are you sure the `$_REQUEST` variable is empty, or are you basing this assumption on a database that's not being altered?

Comment: Have you checked the source of the page to make sure it's actually empty in the HTML?

Comment: Did you try `addslashes()`
example :
`<?php
$str = "Votre nom est-il O'reilly ?";

// Show : Votre nom est-il **O\'reilly** ?
echo addslashes($str);
?>`

Comment: ’ and ' are not the same. The form is being submitted by the <form method="POST" action="post.php" id="form"> It actually is empty in HTML and is also empty in PHP which is really weird. suhosin is not on.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML code

```
<form action="cible.php" method="POST">
Group name: <input type="text" name="user">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP :

```
<?php
$groupname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user'], ENT_QUOTES);
echo $groupname;
?>
```

It's work fine for me

Comment: Tried that but still does not work. The ’ character makes the $_REQUEST variable empty.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have magic quote in your php config ? Try to disable it.